# when $p \mid ab \Rightarrow p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to know when this statement is true ($p$ is a prime):

> $p \mid ab \Rightarrow p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ ?

Comment: Please tell me why downvote?

Comment: I assume it's because you only posted the problem text, with no shred of evidence that you've given this problem any serious thought, and no hints to the people writing you answers where you are stuck so they know where to pick up. As long as the problem itself is well-posed, that's more or less the only reason _anyone_ would downvote a question. Of course, the person who did so may have only skimmed over, seen _two sentences_ and decided "This person isn't worth my time", downvoted, and moved on. I'm only speculating. I should move on before a flaming war starts.

Comment: I don't think this deserved a downvote. +1 to rectify.

Comment: @amWhy: Upvotes should not try to rectify other peoples downvotes. This defies the very logic of voting: you should express your _own_ opinion, independently of what other people think. Besides you cannot know how many people have already "rectified" already (in general, in the current case yours seems to be the unique upvote yet). Votes are not for doing "justice"; any thought of justice in votes is pure illusion anyway.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen I do not cast upvotes, nor downvotes, solely for the reason of rectifying, or "doing justice", and do so only insofar as I see fit. Please do not assume otherwise.

Comment: @Mahdi Khosravi: What do you mean by "when is it true"? If you mean to ask whether for a given prime number $p$ it holds for all (integers I presume) $a,b$, then ask that. Should that statement be false (which happens to not be  the case) then asking when it will holds is not very interesting; it would hold for thaos $a,b$ for which either the hypothesis fails or the conclusion holds; not very surprising. You wouldn't expect such a statement to hold on Mondays, Wednesdays and Saturdays.

Comment: @amWhy: My comment was to "+1 to rectify" in your previous comment; this suggested the contrary to what you now deny.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: I agree with Amy so +)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $p$ is a prime, then your statement$$p \mid ab \implies p \mid a\;\lor p\mid b$$ is always true.

But the proposition is not necessarily true when $p$ is not prime.

For example, suppose $p = 6$ and $a = 2, b = 3$.

Then $6\mid (2\cdot 3)$, but it is **not true** that $6\mid 2$ or that $6\mid 3$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p\neq 0$ and let $p$ not be a unit. Then.

$p$ is a prime if and only if $p|ab$ implies $p|a$ or $p|b$

Here prime in the meaning that $(p)$ is a prime ideal, so there is no distinction between $p$ and $up$ when $u$ is a unit.

There is an alternative definition often used for prime: $p$ is a
prime if $r|p$ implies that $r=1\vee r=up$ where $u$ is a unit.
However this defines irreducibility of $p$ and in many cases $p$
is prime if it is irreducible. But not always. Every prime is irreducible
but the converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: I'm no native speaker, but I assume *separable* should rather be called *reducible*.

Comment: Actually the mentioned condition holds for $\pm1$, $0$, and negatives of primes too. Not serious, but this does not give a good _definition_ of prime number.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes you are right. Quite often I mix these two words. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the former or the latter?

Comment: @miniBill Yesterday I updated. I hope it is oké now. Marc was right in his comment.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yesterday I updated. I hope it is oké now. You were right in your comment.